# How can I bind a Delegate Command to an ApplicationBarIconButton in Windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How can I bind a Delegate command defined in my view model, to an ApplicationBarIconButton of my xaml windows phone 8 app in c#. The ApplicationBarIconButton doesn't have the Command property.

Answer (score 0):

It has a `Click` event. In code behind:

```
myApplicationBarIconButton.Click += yourDelegate;
```

Or in XAML:

```
 <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
        <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Click="yourDelegate" Text="Yo" />
 ...
```

Comment: Error telling me that Event not found in the page. Note I am following MVVM pattern so the delegate command is a property in the viewmodel